# nslookup Returning Domain that is a Subdomain of some Default

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nslookup, dig

I'm the owner of a hypothetical domain name, XYZ.com. I have an LXC container setup that exhibits an undesired behavior:

$ nslookup non-existent-domain-12345.com
Name: non-existent-domain-12345.com.XYZ.com
Address: W.X.Y.Z

Somewhere, I have a misconfiguration. The system knows that my domain is XYZ.com, and decides to map any non-existing domain to be a subdomain of my primary domain.

Answer (score 0):

In resolv.conf, I had a line "search XYZ.com". Removing this line resolved the issue.